# How to model this car hood?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I recently started to model [a car](http://www.aggressivecars.com/modern-muscle-muscles-up-1971-dodge-challenger-rt/) and can't get past the hood :P
I tried many things, ended up with this (not finished, I'm aware of ngons...)
I'm aware that the topology is not right, it has a bad flow and so on.

**So I ask you for advice on how to model such non-traditional hood.**

[image: dodge]

My reference

[image: dodge]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: sorry but Imho this is not a modeling course support forum... I feel that topology should be learned in other ways, and not through a blender related q&a site...

Comment: Probably the best way, would be to trace the curves of the hood, and then fill it in. You should probably go to BlenderArtists.org to get help there.

Comment: @DalekMaker Yes I realized that already... Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of trial and error, [I somehow figured it out myself](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?385770-Dodge-Challenger-1971&p=2969031&viewfull=1#post2969031) :

[image]

however, I'm always opened to your suggestions :)